# Как в Laravel прочитать значение одного из $request-параметров внутри своего риквеста StoreBlogPostRequest?

Tags: laravel, laravel5, laravel-5.6, laravel5.4

Если я валидирую данные запроса через свой риквест:

```
php artisan make:request StoreBlogPostRequest
```

как я могу внутри этого класса прочитать значение одного из параметров этого запроса?

Answer (score 1):

Есть самый простой путь - использовать хелпер. Т.е. обращаться просто по:

```
$request = request();
```

Answer (score 0):

Так как StoreBlogPostRequest наследник от FormRequest, то доступны те же гетеры

```
$this->odin_is_parametrov
```

или

```
$this->get('odin_is_parametrov')
```